# Chebyshev's inequality question on theorem

Tags: probability

> Chebyshev's inequality: suppose $\varphi: R \rightarrow R$ has $\varphi \ge 0$. Let $A \in \mathcal{R}$ and $ i_A=\{ \textbf{inf} \varphi(y);y \in A \}$. Then $$i_AP(X \in A) \le E(\varphi(x):X \in A) \le E \varphi(X)$$.

I have hard time understanding what does $i_AP(X \in A)$ indicate (the infimum of a function that has probability of all elements in a Borel set?) and why does the inequality $$i_AP(X \in A) \le E(\varphi(x):X \in A) \le E \varphi(X)$$  make sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like "Chebyshev's inequality made hard."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $i_A$ is supposed to be a number, so $i_A P[X \in A]$ is the multiplication of the number $i_A$ with the number $P[X \in A]$.

You can prove it by the following inequality of random variables: Assuming $\phi$ is a nonnegative function, we have
$$ \left(\inf_{y \in A} \phi(y)\right) 1_{X \in A} \leq \phi(X) 1_{X \in A} \leq \phi(X)$$
where $1_{X \in A}$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $X \in A$ (and 0 else). Taking expectations gives
$$\underbrace{\left(\inf_{y \in A} \phi(y)\right)}_{i_A} P[X \in A]  \leq \underbrace{E[\phi(X) 1_{X \in A}]}_{E[\phi(X): X \in A]} \leq E[\phi(X)]$$

Comment: So a possible point of confusion is that the number $i_A$ is defined based on a single known $\phi$ function, where $\phi$ never changes. It could also be called $i_{\phi, A}$ or just $\inf_{y \in A} \phi(y)$ to avoid confusion.  It is not an operator that acts on a general function that comes after it.